# Access or modify tnsnames.ora on AWS Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, aws

I have an Oracle RDS instance running on AWS and I need to access the `tnsnames.ora` file and check its configuration since I am getting this error

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

which is directly connected these two following resolutions

- [How to Fix 'ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor'](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-fix-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor/)
- [TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/listener-refused-the-connection-with-following-error-ora-12505-tns-listener-d)

the problem is that AWS [does NOT allow remote access to the Oracle RDS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=38599) and I cannot find anything in the AWS console which would help me change or even access the contents of the `tnsnames.ora`.

Can I maybe do it using SQL? I'm at my wits end here... This error does not even seem to be consistent since for example some queries do work....

///
Adding more info after reading some comments:

Queries like the following are successfully executed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (

SELECT
  DISTINCT tab.column_a, tab.column_a AS L0, tab.column_a AS L1, tab.column_a AS L2
FROM
  ADMIN.table_something tab
WHERE
  tab.column_a IS NOT NULL 

)
```

the ones that fail look like this

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT tab.column_a, tab.column_a AS L0, tab.column_a AS L1, tab.column_a AS L2
FROM
  ADMIN.table_something tab
WHERE
  tab.column_a IS NOT NULL
```

and by fail I mean producing the error I mentioned above. Executing these from a SQL command prompt produces no errors.

I am using this jdbc URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_URL>:1521:SID
```

I also tried using this format

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_URL>:1521/ServiceNames
```

But apparently the AWS RDS instance is not configured with service names. Most of the answers I've found refer to the `tnsnames.ora` as the place where the service names and sids are configured and therefore includes information on how to actually form a connection string. This is why I want to access it and if I find something suspicious then modify it.

Comment: Tell us what throws the `ORA-12505` error and why do you think changing `tnsnames.ora` will solve that.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I updated the question with the information you asked. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Is it java program or third party ide?

Comment: @Kumar it is a Scala application build with Play framework.

Comment: If executing from sqlplus has no problem implies that the problem lies with scala application and the error is most likely due to malformed jdbc url.Can you post result of tnsping?.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to section "Configuring tnsnames.ora" on the below article.

[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/configuring-and-using-oracle-connection-manager-on-amazon-ec2-for-amazon-rds-for-oracle/#:~:text=ora%20or%20tnsnames.,in%20Amazon%20RDS%20for%20Oracle](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/configuring-and-using-oracle-connection-manager-on-amazon-ec2-for-amazon-rds-for-oracle/#:%7E:text=ora%20or%20tnsnames.,in%20Amazon%20RDS%20for%20Oracle).

Comment: Please don't create link-only answers. They break and become useless if/when the address changes or disappears.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.